# If Harry isn't going home, then where is he going?

Tags: harry-potter

On the train back from Hogwarts, Hagrid gifts Harry Potter with a book. Harry then gets on the train:

> Hermione Granger: Feels strange to be going home, doesn't it?
>
> Harry Potter: **I'm not going home. Not really.**

If Harry isn't going home, then where is he going?

Comment: Harry is going back to Privet Drive, but he's saying that his home is Hogwarts.

Comment: @Roberto want to turn that into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [screenplay](https://8flix.com/assets/screenplays/h/tt0241527/Harry-Potter-and-the-Sorcerers-Stone-2001-screenplay-by-Steve-Kloves.pdf) makes it clear that Harry no longer considers the Muggle world and the house on Privet Drive where he lives with his aunt and uncle to be his his home. He stares wistfully out of the window at Hogwarts Castle and the Wizarding World™, his *true* (metaphorical) home.

[image]

Comment: Note that Harry isn't actually a wizard and all of this is occurring in his mind as he sleeps in his closet with the spiders.

Comment: But "While you can still call home the place where your mother’s blood dwells, there you cannot be touched or harmed by Voldemort." (OotP)

Comment: @RalfFriedl - I don't think anyone ever accused these films of consistency.